# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'slice'

Tags: python

I'm writing a Sublime2 plugin and fighting a bit.

Code is:

```
  def run(self, edit):
    self.edit            = edit
    self.view.window().show_input_panel("New Controller and View Path (ex: client_area/index )", "", self.trigger, None, None)

  def trigger(self, user_entry):
    formatted_entry = user_entry.encode('utf-8')
    print formatted_entry.__class__
    print formatted_entry
    if formatted_entry.slice('/')[0] == '':
      #some code
```

Output is:

```
<type 'str'>
client_area/index
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./PluginName.py", line 27, in trigger
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'slice'
```

How is it I get `'str' object has no attribute 'slice'` ? (Python version is 2.6)

Comment: Don't you mean 'split' ?

Comment: I think you normally slice like `"asdasd"[1:3]` ... ahh I think bradley.ayers got it ... I didnt figure it out :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings don't have a `slice` method in Python - did you mean [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (or some variation thereof, such as [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rsplit))?

Comment: Silly me... signal to tell it's time to go to bed I guess

Comment: Same here. Too much JS in my life

Answer (score 0):

`$`slice() method doesn't works with pandas.Series so first we have to convert it into
StringMethods by using .str then we can apply slice notation.

> > s=pd.Series(["2020", "2010", "2013"])
> > s
> > 0        2020
> > 1        2010
> > 2        2013
> > dtype: object
> > s.slice() # doesn't work
> > s.str.slice(2,4).astype(int)
> > 0    20
> > 1    10
> > 2    13
> > dtype: int32